# Deploy Angular 1.x App to Nginx

Tags: angularjs, nginx, deployment, production

I'm trying to deploy an angular app to a linux production server using nginx.

The app is a modified version of the angular-seed project from [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), the app is fully functional and working fine from the local server (npm start on my local machine, like the link says).

But when deploying to nginx everything stops working and i end up with the index page with no views loaded and not functional links.

Here's the nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.domain.com

    root /home/user/angular/app;

    index index.html;    

    location / {
    root /home/user/angular/app;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure that's even correct, but at least it displays something other than "Welcome to Nginx"

Here's app.js

```
angular.module('test', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ui.knob',
  'test.home',
  'test.company',
  'test.companyList'
])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "/home/home.html",
        controller : "homeController"
    })
    .when("/companyList", {
        templateUrl : "/company_list/companyList.html",
        controller : "listController"
    })
    .when("/company/:companyName", {
        templateUrl : "/company_page/company.html",
        controller : "companyController"
    });

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

[Folder view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZMi7.png)

Any Ideas?
Thanks

UPDATE: 
I added {{ "Angular Test" }} at the top of the page to see wheter angular was working and in dev it shows the message only while in production it shows the {{}} as well, But if i type angular into the console i get an object. 
Maybe a dependency is failing or sth?

Comment: Did you bundle the entire app via Gulp or equivalent?

Comment: @MikeTung I did not, should I?

Comment: yes... cause it makes a single bundle.js and html file for you that you can juse use to deploy